# Как сделать данную функцию не рекурсивной?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
double getXn(uint8_t n, double X0)
{
    double Xn;

    if (n == 1) return X0;
    Xn = getXn(n - 1) + (8 / pow(getXn(n - 1), 2));

    return Xn;
}
```

Comment: Этот код некорректен. Вопрос бессмыслен из-за некорректности постановки. Потрудитесь внимательнее формулировать вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double x = x0;

for (unsigned q=1; q<n; ++q)
  x = x + 8 / (x*x);

return x;
```

Comment: У вас в цикле лишняя итерация

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, разве? У него от 1 до n включительно, у меня от 0 до n невключительно - в обоих случаях ровно n итераций.

Comment: У автора получается [1;n), https://ideone.com/gaj71d

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, убедил)) Исправил.